# Product mix forecasting method

Tags: forecasting

I have a main segment which includes different products. I have the percentages for each product and two year quarterly data. By using this information I want to forecast next years' percentages. I know data history is small (only 8 quarters of data), I would like to learn what will be the best method to predict the next quarters. I am giving an example of data below. Each year's is total 100%.

Thank you,

```
Products      Q12015 Q22015 Q32015 Q42015 Q12016 Q22016 Q32016 Q42016
A             0%      15%    25%    30%    30%   20%     15%    10%
B             40%     20%    15%    20%    20%   10%     30%    40%
C             20%     30%    25%    30%    10%   40%     20%    20%
D             40%     35%    35%    20%    40%   30%     35%    30%
```

Comment: As a quick fix, you could try predicting three of them, hope they don't exceed 100 together, and the last product is just the remainder.